# Is anything in the Video Resource optional for uploading?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm struggling to find an answer to what seems like a simple question, I'm quite new to the YouTube API and I've been tasked with upgrading our integration from the 2.0 API to 3.0 at work (late, I know).

It seems like to upload a video there's a lot of data that needs to be sent up with a video upload and I'm trying to figure out what parameters I can leave blank and which I have to set and send up.

I'm assuming that things such as content rating can be left blank and will be automatically set but before I start skipping things I was wondering if anyone knew what was the bare minimal that needs to be attached to a video upload for the API to accept it. I've gone through the docs but it seems to just list everything without any "required / optional" flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
snippet.title
snippet.description
snippet.categoryId
status.privacyStatus
```

are the bare minimal for the video resource inside the [videos->insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method.